# how to pass argument using metaclass

Tags: arguments, metaclass

Python has a method `__init__subclass` using it I can pass argument as class variable

but when I use `__init__subclass` with metaclass, argument in the class definition can not passed to `__init__subclass`.

blew is my code, can anyone figure out how to pass argument to `__init__subclass` when using metaclass?

```
class person(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, base, namespace, *args, **kwargs):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, base, namespace)

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(name, bases, *args, **kwargs):
        dict1 = {}
        dict1['a'] = 1
        return dict1


class teacher(metaclass=person):

    def __init_subclass__(cls, default_name, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        print('begin initilize subclass')
        print(kwargs)
        cls.default_name = default_name




class teacherwdname(teacher, default_name='kevin'):
    teach = 'physics'


c = teacherwdname()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to forward the keyword-arguments to `type.__new__` - in your implementation, you are swallowing them in  `type.__new__(cls, name, base, namespace)`

Look at it working when you just forward them:

```py
In [1]: class Meta(type): 
   ...:     def __new__(mcls, names, bases, namespace, **kw): 
   ...:         return super().__new__(mcls, names, bases, namespace, **kw) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: class Base(metaclass=Meta): 
   ...:     def __init_subclass__(cls, test_param, **kw): 
   ...:         print(f"Initializing with {test_param}") 
   ...:          
   ...:          
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                 

In [3]: class A(Base, test_param="testing"): pass                                                                                                                       
Initializing with testing
```

Comment: You are right, thank you ! interesting same arguments passed several times.

Comment: They are not passed "several times" - You hav to understand that when you deal with metaclasses, you are actually changing the "plumbing" Python uses to create classes. It _is_ type.__new__`  which is respnsible for calling  `__init_subclass__`  - it could not do it if it did not have the arguments.
(one can argue that this call should be done on `type.__call__` when it acts as the "meta-meta-class" and orchestrates the calls to the metaclass' `__new__` and `__init__`, but it is just not built that way)